# Makefile undefined reference

Tags: c, makefile

I understand why this error is happening, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's my setup:

- extra.c : contains some auxiliary function definitions
- extra.h : contains the prototypes & includes for extra.c
- foo.c : my main program that imports utils.h

My Makefile is as follows:

```
CC=gcc
foo_CFLAGS=-Wall

all: foo

clean: 
    rm -f foo *.o

install:
    install -m 0755 foo /bin

PRIMARY_TARGETS = foo.o other_stuff.o more_stuff.o
SECONDARY_TARGETS = extra.o

foo: $(PRIMARY_TARGETS) $(SECONDARY_TARGETS)
    $(CC) $(foo_CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(PRIMARY_TARGETS): %.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c $(foo_CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(SECONDARY_TARGETS): %.o: %.c utils_folder/utils.c
    $(CC) -c $(foo_CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

FYI the targets are split into primary and secondary because some utils.c functions need to be referenced in extra.c

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
undefined reference to `my_utils_function_1'
```

Did I approach the secondary targets part the wrong way? Isn't the issue that the linker needs to know about that utils.c file in order to define/implement the missing function in extra.c?

**EDIT**

Here's the Makefile stacktrace:

```
| foo.o: In function `foo_init':
| /home/build/foo.c:33: undefined reference to `my_utils_function_1'
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| Makefile:17: recipe for target 'foo' failed
| make: *** [foo] Error 1
```

Comment: or you didn't code `my_utils_function_1`, only defined its prototype. Can you show us a snippet of the function definition? can you post a trace of the makefile full execution (link step, actually)

Comment: I did, I'm currently looking at it. The problem is I can't post actual code (as you can probably tell from my description) cause this is a work project. I was more so wondering if there was anything inherently wrong with my methodology.

Comment: of course! post makefile execution traces and just the definition of your function (in the .c file). that won't disclose any confidential code.

Comment: which file contains the implementation  source of 'my_utils_function_1'?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I posted as much of the stacktrace as I could; unfortunately this is wrapped in a much bigger project. I can't really post the function definition but I've confirmed that there are no spelling errors or anything and that it is defined

Comment: @pm100 It's in utils.c

Comment: As written these rules only make sense if `extra.c` contains the line `#include "utils_folder/utils.c"`.  Even then it is questionable, as it will be nonsense if you add a second file to `SECONDARY_TARGETS`.  Where (which compilation unit) are you expecting `my_utils_function_1` to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't reference utils.o in PRIMARY or SECONDARY, so they are not linked –

Comment: utils.o shouldn't actually get built. The functions of utils.c are used to make extra.o but it isn't used beyond that.

Comment: Scratch that, you were right. I needed to generate utils.o and link later